# How to get quality of image in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

I've been doing some speed optimization on my site using Page Speed and it gives recommendations like so:

```
Optimizing the following images could reduce their size by 35.3KiB (21% reduction).

Losslessly compressing http://example.com/.../some_image.jpg could save 25.3KiB (55% reduction).
```

How are the calculations done to get the file size reduction numbers? How can I determine if an image is optimized in PHP?

As I understand it, they seem to base this on the image quality (so saving at 60% in Photoshop or so is considered optimized?).

What I would like to do is once an image is uploaded, check if the image is fully optimized, if not, then optimize it using a PHP image library such as GD or ImageMagick. If I'm right about the number being based on quality, then I will just reduce the quality as needed.

How can I determine if an image is fully optimized in the standards that Page Speed uses?

Comment: As far as i am concern, i think there is no attribute as quality in images, it needs to be something else width, height may be bit depth, alpha channels ...etc

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression

Comment: @user1179459 I did some tests by saving the same image as 100% and 30% quality in Photoshop and horizontal/vertical resolution as well as bit depth were identical.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, as you're looking to integrate this automagically into your workflow, but looks like part of this was asked over on webmasters.stackexchange.com: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23340/how-can-i-replicate-google-page-speeds-lossless-image-compression-as-part-of-my

Comment: Looks like google suggests some libraries to use in their docs in the "Use an image compressor" section: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#CompressImages

Comment: @ernie ya, I'm looking for a programming solution as I can't rely on users uploading perfectly optimized images.

Comment: Finally, this page seems to state which libraries they use: http://code.google.com/p/page-speed/wiki/ImageCompression

Answer (score 2):

Chances are they are simply using a standard compression or working on some very simple rules to calculate image compression/quality. It isn't exactly what you were after but what I often use on uploaded images etc etc dynamic content is a class called SimpleImage:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

this will give you the options to resize & adjust compression, and I think even change image type (by which I mean .jpg to .png or .gif anything you like). I worked in seo and page optimization was a huge part of my Job I generally tried to make the images the size the needed to be no smaller or bigger. compress JS & CSS and that's really all most people need to worry about.

Comment: I am actually using a similar approach using Codeigniter's Image Manipulation library. Does your solution satisfy Page Speed? I'm beginning to think Page Speed may be complaining about extra meta data...

Comment: Well yes I believe it should, simply because as you get down to it page optimization is very simple. just simply reduce file size as much as you can. using the inspector on chrome and most other browsers is really your best friend. Reduces DNS Lookups,Images Sizes, Be careful about how you embed video, I recommend the youtube player for SEO purposes. if you can load big media after the fact I'm refering to video/audio if you aren't fussed too bad about SEO flash avoid it like its the plague. it's really common sense.

Comment: i think this question is not about the reducing the image size i think its about the reducing the image without making it too optimised and loose the original quality.. he asking can we have quality attribute to be readable..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use the PageSpeed Insights API to get the compressions scores: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/reference, though I'm guessing you'd want to run a quality check/compression locally, rather than sending everything through this API.

It also looks like they've got a standalone image optimizer available at http://code.google.com/p/page-speed/wiki/DownloadPageSpeed?tm=2, though this appears to be a Windows binary.  They've got an SDK there as well, though I haven't looked into what it entails, or how easy it would be to integrate into an existing site.